# is f: Z x Z → Z onto, where f(m,n)=m^2+n

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have a good understanding of onto functions, one-to-one functions. However the problem here as I am having is the how would one graph this function. For ex. if f(x)=x then we know its onto since for every pre-image there is an image. But this function I cannot seem to create a visual of how this functions looks like. If you can help me with that I may be able to proceed with this function.

Comment: What happens when $m=0$?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not know what you mean

Comment: Your function associates a pair of integers to another integer. So, $(1,2)$ is associated with $3$, for example. I said that $(0,n)$ is associated with $n$ and therefore $f$ is onto.

Comment: @JonasGomes I understand all of what you have said. Just a last quick question. Why do we only pick (0,n)? Why not (m,0)?

Comment: If we'd pick $(m,0)$ the function would be $m^2$, which is not onto as you probably knows.

Comment: Yes that's true and you do get onto but why pick (0,n)? Isn't a function onto if it is onto for anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18332/discussion-between-gurinderhans-and-jonas-gomes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is indeed onto.  We must show that for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ there exists $(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(m,n) = k$.  If $k=0$ take the pair $(0,0)$, clearly $f(0,0) = 0$.  Now consider the set of squares $S = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: n = l^2\}$ for some integer $l$.  Take $m \in S$ such $m$ is the maximum element of $S$ less than or equal to the integer $k$.  Then we are done if we let $n = k - m^2$ by definition of $f$ at $(m,n)$ since $f(m,k - m^2) = m^2 + k - m^2 = k$.